# Dealing with multiple categorical inputs and variable-sized groups as inputs to neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, embedding

I'm working with data which consists of numerical and categorical features, where each input consists of a variable-sized group of the features.
For example: predict the price of a house by using features about each room in the house, and each house could have a different amount of rooms. The features could be size in meters, type (e.g living room/bathroom/bedroom), color, floor...
Some of the categorical features have high cardinality, and I may be using many features.
I'd want to use the features from n rooms to predict the price for each house.
How would I structure my inputs/nn model to receive variable-sized groups of inputs?

I thought of using one-hot encoding, but then I'd end up with large input vectors and I'd lose the connections between the features for each room.
I also thought of using embeddings, but I'm not sure what the best way is to combine the features/samples to properly input all the data without losing any info about which features come from which samples etc.

Answer (score 0):

As the article, linked below, suggests... you've got one of three routes to choose from.

- Ordinal Encoding which I am thinking is not the right use case for your example
- One Hot Encoding which you've ruled out efficiently.
- Difference Encoding, which is I think a little bit suited as there are master bedrooms, minor ones, guest ones and children ones. So, try that angle.

[Link to the beautiful article](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-overview-of-categorical-input-handling-for-neural-networks-c172ba552dee)

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you, the article was very informative. I'm still unclear about how to process a variable group size for each sample though, do you have any thoughts on the issue?